# Variable cast as protocol instance not the same underlying type as variable of class instance?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Given that the underlying types are the same, I expected `test2` to be `true`, not `false`:

```swift
protocol Foo {}
class Bar: NSObject, Foo {}
class Test {
    func testCompare() {
        let b = Bar()
        let test1 = compare(expected: Bar.self, actual: b)
        let c: Foo = b
        let test2 = compare(expected: Bar.self, actual: c)
        /*
         (lldb) p expected
         (@thick NSObject.Type) $R0 = SpokestackTests.Bar
         (lldb) p type(of: actual).self
         (SpokestackTests.Foo.Type) $R2 = SpokestackTests.Bar
        */
        print(test1, test2) // true false
    }
    
    func compare<T>(expected: NSObject.Type, actual: T) -> Bool {
        return expected == type(of: actual).self
    }
}
```

Is this due to the difference between a concrete metatype of a class vs the existential metatype of a protocol instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After taking a look at the documentation of [type(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) function we can rephrase the last paragraph to something like this:

> This unexpected result occurs because the call to `type(of: value)`
> inside `compare(expected:actual:)` must return a metatype that is an
> instance of `T.Type` which is the static type of `actual` parameter
> (`Foo.self`). To get the dynamic type inside value in this generic
> context, cast the parameter to Any when calling type(of:).

or just change the `compare(expected:actual:)` function to use `Any` type instead of generics:

```
private func compare(expected: NSObject.Type, actual: Any) -> Bool {
    return expected == type(of: actual).self
}
```

**Update**: Even better you can use @Jessy suggestion in the comments

```
func compare<Expected: Foundation.NSObject>(expected: Expected.Type, actual: Any) -> Bool {
    return type(of: actual) is Expected.Type
}
```

Comment: Probably better expressed as : 
```func compare<Expected: Foundation.NSObject>(
  expected _: Expected.Type, actual: Any
) -> Bool {
  type(of: actual) is Expected.Type
}
```

Comment: @Jessy yes, this is probably better. I updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Is the explanation for the `type(of:)` behavior that since `Any` is both a value and reference type (and function type!), casting the `actual` type to `Any` allows the Swift type system to resolve the difference between a concrete metatype of a class vs the existential metatype of a protocol instance?

Comment: @Noel yes. Casting it as `Any` practically breaks free of the generic context.

Answer (score 0):

It can make a comparison with your function as compare same object

It can't make a comparison metatype with an instance so returns false
These ones returns false as well you can try in the pg :

```
    let d: Any = b
    _ = compare(expected: Bar.self, actual: d)
    
    d as! Foo
    _ = compare(expected: Bar.self, actual: d)
```